# Show original ip with cloudflare

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

I installed nginx and the HttpRealipModule to get the original ip of my visitors.I also add this in the http{ } part in my nginx.conf

```
  set_real_ip_from   204.93.240.0/24;
  set_real_ip_from   204.93.177.0/24;
  set_real_ip_from   199.27.128.0/21;
  set_real_ip_from   173.245.48.0/20;
  set_real_ip_from   103.22.200.0/22;
  set_real_ip_from   141.101.64.0/18;
  set_real_ip_from   108.162.192.0/18;
  set_real_ip_from   190.93.240.0/20;
  real_ip_header     CF-Connecting-IP;
```

However when i do

```
netstat -atun | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sed -e '/^$/d' |sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

To find out the ip address of my visitors , all the ip i get has ISP as Cloudflare(i traced those ip)
Any idea why its not showing the original ip

-Some other question 
I want to limit the number of concurrent connections people use while downloading from my site.If i use  limit_conn 4; it will do the job but if user is downloading and try to access site from browser he/she get 503 unavailable.Is there a way to limit connections but still allow users to view site simultaneously

Answer (score 1):

You're not seeing the web browser's IP address from `netstat` because the connections are coming from CloudFlare. This is how CloudFlare works.

To see the IP addresses you need to look at your nginx logs.

Comment: That looks like a separate question. Posting two questions at once is frowned on here; they should be posted separately.